# Ubuntu headphone jack not working

Tags: asus, headphones, jack

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit on an Asus laptop and my headphone jack isn't working. I had Windows 10 before I had Ubuntu and every time I put in the headphones, I would have to plug it in and plug it out a couple of times and a window would pop p asking which device I plugged in. But now that I have Ubuntu, it doesn't work at all and I've tried using instructions on here for terminal and that didn't work. (I only have Ubuntu because my mom gave me a Wacom tablet for drawing and she tried to download the drawing app but it made my laptop not work after and we got someone at my church to fix it and he for some reason put Ubuntu on it)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you checked if your sound is muted?

Is your laptop speaker working?

If so, then try to reset your audio drivers by doing this:

`sudo apt-get --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-uname -r linux-ubuntu-modules-uname -r libasound2`

Comment: Everything is working fine, it's just when I put in my earbuds it won't play sound like it used to before. Also, I did the command but it said command not found.

Comment: @Aifang I edited the answer and changed aptitude to apt. Try the updated command.

Comment: Still didn't work. It said "Command line option --purge is not understood in combination with the other options"

Comment: @Aifang I edited it again and added -get. Try it.

Comment: It said the same thing :/

Comment: @Aifang try with `purge` instead of `--purge` and without `reinstall`, then run the command in the answer without `--purge`.